# How to update a table in DB1 after another table in DB2 update in sql server?

Tags: sql

I have two database and I want update table2 in database2 when table1 in database1 is updating.
I want to do this in sql server not in code in Visual studio . How can I do that?

Comment: Create a trigger. Do some research, post your code if you have issues.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, the most straightforward solution would be to create a trigger for update. Something like here [Trigger to update table in another DB](http://forums.devshed.com/ms-sql-development-95/trigger-update-data-db-149985.html)

If you don't need on-the-fly synchronization you could also create a scheduled SP running in the night, for example, as a trigger can slow down your update queries.